# Searching in subdirectories

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I need to count the total number of pages in a big directory with thousands of pdf files. After finding a similar code like here below, I noticed that the code is **NOT** searching in **subdirectories**. Can anybody help me by redefining the code?

Pdf files are named as following: name_year_*.pdf. Example car1_2020_diesel.pdf

```
Sub Test()
Dim I As Long
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xStr As String
Dim xFd As FileDialog
Dim xFdItem As Variant
Dim xFileName As String
Dim xFileNum As Long
Dim RegExp As Object
Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If xFd.Show = -1 Then
    xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
    xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*_2020_*.pdf", vbDirectory)
    Set xRg = Range("A1")
    Range("A:B").ClearContents
    Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
    xRg = "File Name"
    xRg.Offset(0, 1) = "Pages"
    I = 2
    xStr = ""
    Do While xFileName <> ""
        Cells(I, 1) = xFileName
        Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBscript.RegExp")
        RegExp.Global = True
        RegExp.Pattern = "/Type\s*/Page[^s]"
        xFileNum = FreeFile
        Open (xFdItem & xFileName) For Binary As #xFileNum
            xStr = Space(LOF(xFileNum))
            Get #xFileNum, , xStr
        Close #xFileNum
        Cells(I, 2) = RegExp.Execute(xStr).Count
        I = I + 1
        xFileName = Dir
    Loop
    Columns("A:B").AutoFit
End If
End sub
```

Comment: Can you throw out all the lines from your code that don't have any relation to the issue your question is about?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the File System Object Library to access subfolders.

A general way of doing this would be to isolate the elements of your code that acts on the files inside of a folder and make it a separate procedure. You could then use a procedure that would call that simpler procedure and loop recursively on subfolders:

```
Sub RunMacroOnFolderAndSubFolders(ByVal MacroName As String, Optional ByVal FolderName As String)

    If FolderName = vbNullString Then
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show = -1 Then
                FolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
    End If
    
    'Run the macro on this folder
    Application.Run Macro:=MacroName, Arg1:=FolderName
    
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    'Iterate on subfolders
    Dim FSOFolder As Object
    For Each FSOFolder In FSO.GetFolder(FolderName).SubFolders
        RunMacroOnFolderAndSubFolders MacroName:=MacroName, FolderName:=FSOFolder.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    Next

End Sub
```

In your case, seems like the macro with just the code that acts on files of a folder would look like this :

```
Sub Test(ByVal FolderName As String)

    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFileName As String
    Dim xFileNum As Long
    Dim RegExp As Object

    xFileName = Dir(FolderName & "*_2020_*.pdf", vbNormal)
    Set xRg = Range("A1")
    Range("A:B").ClearContents
    Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
    xRg = "File Name"
    xRg.Offset(0, 1) = "Pages"
    I = 2
    xStr = ""
    Do While xFileName <> ""
        Cells(I, 1) = xFileName
        Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBscript.RegExp")
        RegExp.Global = True
        RegExp.Pattern = "/Type\s*/Page[^s]"
        xFileNum = FreeFile
        Open (FolderName & xFileName) For Binary As #xFileNum
            xStr = Space(LOF(xFileNum))
            Get #xFileNum, , xStr
        Close #xFileNum
        Cells(I, 2) = RegExp.Execute(xStr).Count
        I = I + 1
        xFileName = Dir
    Loop
    Columns("A:B").AutoFit

End Sub
```

NOTE: Procedures with parameters (even if they are optional) can't be called directly (outside of another procedure), so you would have to do something like this to run it :

```
Sub RunMacroOnFolderAndSubFoldersTest()
    RunMacroOnFolderAndSubFolders MacroName:="Test"
End Sub
```

Comment: While FileSystemObject is one way to go, there _are_ ways to traverse a folder/subfolder structure using Dir.  Searching SO will reveal many ways to do that

Comment: I didn't really mean to say it's the only way, but I see how my wording gave this impression. I've edited the answer to appear more nuanced.

Comment: The code is running good until the first match. The filename and total number of pages are pasted in the resp. columns. Continuations seems to stuck. The progress circle keeps turning but there is no progress while just below the 1st founded item is again an item who is matching with *_2020_*

Comment: @Jesse – First, I realize that your code was using vbDirectory instead of vbNormal for the Dir function, so I've edited my answer to fix that since we want the Dir function to return only file names. Is it possible that you had only one file in the main folder and the other files are in subfolders?